# Make data rotation with MariaDB database

Tags: database-design, mariadb, innodb, partitioning, configuration

We have a small local computer that we use as a temporary database backup to automatically recover data from sensors when we lost connection to the main cloud server or when we have to make maintenance to this server.

Due to the small space disk available for data (32go) the idea was to keep last 3 month of sensors data and delete oldest entries.

Here is the description of the database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `machine` (
  `Nom` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Site` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Emplacement` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Nom` (`Nom`),
  KEY `FK__site` (`Site`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK__site` FOREIGN KEY (`Site`) REFERENCES `site` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=77 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mesure` (
  `Machine` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Valeur` decimal(13,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Machine`,`Date`),
  KEY `Date` (`Date`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK__machine` FOREIGN KEY (`Machine`) REFERENCES `machine` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `site` (
  `Nom` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In a first time I thought that making periodic deletion will be sufficent but I discovered that innoDB does not release space disk to the OS, and now the disk partition is full (filled in 4 month). More, these delete are bit slow.

After some researches I found that partitions can be the solution to my issue but it seems that it's not possible to make partition with a foreign key inside the table.

Tried this code, just for testing purpose :

```
ALTER TABLE mesure
PARTITION BY RANGE(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date))
(
    PARTITION START VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2021-10-01 00:00:00")),
    PARTITION MONTH1 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2021-11-01 00:00:00")),
    PARTITION MONTH2 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2021-12-01 00:00:00")),
    PARTITION MONTH3 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2022-01-01 00:00:00")),
    PARTITION END VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
    
);
```

That results to : `/* Erreur SQL (1217) : Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails */`

I'm now run out solutions to make this solution viable on our hardware.

Any idea on how I can manage this ?

Comment: Remove FK, check using trigger logic.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest weekly partitions, else you need to hold nearly 4 months worth before dropping the oldest.  More discussion of partitioning for time-series:  [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)

Once you have debugged the code, there is no real need for `FOREIGN KEYs`, so do without them.  (Then add suitable indexes, if needed.)

`decimal(13,2)` takes 6 bytes; consider `FLOAT`, which takes 4.  (But look at range and rounding issues before deciding.)

Could you change any of the `SMALLINTs` (2 bytes`) to` TINYINT` (1 byte)?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to this problem could be to implement a ring buffer. This is possible in MariaDB since version 10.3. The ring buffer idea was first described on [Federico Razzoli](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/145212/federico-razzoli)'s old blog which is no longer available.

- You will need a non-compound primary key for your `measure` table, e.g. `ID int unsigned`.
- You will need to [create a sequence](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-sequence/) with your choice of `maxvalue`.
- When writing to the table, use [`REPLACE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replace/) rather than `INSERT`. Also, use the sequence to get the next available ID.

In other words, something like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE measure_seq
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  MINVALUE=1
  MAXVALUE=10000000
  CYCLE;
```

And then write data like this:

```
REPLACE INTO measure (ID, ...) 
  VALUES (NEXTVAL(measure_seq), ...);
```

This way, the table will never have more rows than your chosen maxvalue as it will overwrite old values with new ones when it reaches that limit. Also, you won't have to worry about managing partitions.